# Access a form value in one frame from another frame

Tags: html, forms, vbscript, frameset

I have created two frames with two different forms as shown in link below:

http://demo.4page.info/framedemo/main.html (Please view in IE)

Now, when I click on `Get Text` button, a predefined value should display in the text box above it, and then when I click on the `Copy Here` button the same value from `textbox1` should display in the text box above it.

So my question is how to access that value in second frames form by clicking copy here button?

Below is my code:

```
<!--main.html-->
<html>
<head>
<frameset cols="50%, 50%">  
    <frame name="f1" src="left.html" />
    <frame name="f2" src="right.html"  />
</frameset>
</head>
</html>
```

This successfully divides page into two frames.

```
<!--left.html-->
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
<script type="text/vbscript">
  dim msg
  msg="Hello"
  function func()
    document.form1.text1.value=msg
  end function
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <form name="form1">
  <table align="center" cellspacing="5">
    <tr><td><input type="text" name="text1" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="button" value="Get Text" onClick="func()" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset" /></td></tr>
  </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

`left.html` is working properly and accessing value on button click.

```
<!--right.html-->
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css" />
<script type="text/vbscript">

</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="form2">
  <table align="center" cellspacing="5">
    <tr><td><input type="text" name="text2" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="button" value="Copy Here!" onClick="??????" /></td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset" /></td></tr>
  </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

What do I have to put in `right.html`?

Answer (score 0):

You can access content of other frames via the `frames` property of the `parent` object, so something like this should work:

```
<script type="text/vbscript">
Sub CopyHere
  document.form2.text2.value = parent.frames("f1").document.form1.text1.value
End Sub
</script>
...
<form name="form2">
  <input type="text" name="text2" /></td></tr>
  <input type="button" value="Copy Here!" onClick="CopyHere()" />
</form>
```

Note that you may need to adjust your browser's security settings for the code to work.

On a more general note I'd recommend using `id` attributes instead of `name` attributes, because the latter is deprecated.